# 404 - Http the requested is not available JavaEE Spring MVC

Tags: spring, java-ee-6

I am not very familiar with Spring MVC DriverManagerDataSource.I am trying to return a JSP from my controller. My Controller method is running well  but when returning view, I'm getting a 404 error.

I don't know why I got this error If I'm telling this: in the web.xml

---

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

---

spring-servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation = 
    "
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    "> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="controllers"></context:component-scan> <!-- com.javatpoint. -->
    
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">    
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>    
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>    
    </bean>   
    
    <bean class = "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name = "driverClassName" value = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name = "url" value = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/empleados"></property>
        <property name = "username" value = "---"></property>
        <property name = "password" value = "---"></property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="jt" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">    
        <property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>    
    </bean> 
    
    <bean id = "dao" class = "dao.EmpDao">
        <property name = "template" ref = "jt"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>SpringMVC</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

HomeController.java

```
package EjemploCRUD.SpringMVC.controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public ModelAndView test(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }
}
```

MvcConfiguration.java

```
package EjemploCRUD.SpringMVC.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="EjemploCRUD.SpringMVC")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    
}
```

Error

```
Type Status Report

Message The requested resource [/SpringMVC/] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

---

folder structure,

[image]

---

Comment: please share the import statement for ModelAndView in your controller (HomeController.java) class

Comment: why you used both (xml and java) configurations methods in your application. please share the folder structure of application

Comment: I shared an image due to I do not have enough reputation :(

Comment: please refer below answer

Answer (score 0):

in your application you used both (java-based and xml-based) configuration types. in this answer, used the xml-based configuration.

try with following steps.

modify the spring-servlet.xml file as follows,

```
<context:component-scan base-package="controllers, EjemploCRUD.SpringMVC.controller"></context:component-scan>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

config the location of spring-servlet.xml file in web.xml file as follows,

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

in your application spring-servlet.xml and web.xml files are located under the WEB-INF/views directory.but these files not relevant to the view.hence, please move these two files into WEB-INF folder(best practice).

as per the web.xml file, configured the views (jsp files) path is WEB-INF/views directory. but in your folder structure index.jsp file is located under the WEB-INF folder. hence, get this error. please move index.jsp file into WEB-INF/views folder.